# count documents by specific nested fields values with aggregation-framework in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here's my db.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("579cab6c6aba30f42a57a979"),
"iecode" : "P1111",
"country" : "India",
"totalTreatmentArms" : 3,
"treatmentArms" : [ 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Mechanism",
        "mechanism" : "mechanism1"
    }, 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Mechanism",
        "mechanism" : "mechanism2"
    }, 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Package",
        "mechanism" : "mechanism1"
    }
]
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("579cab7a6aba30f42a57a97a"),
"iecode" : "P1111",
"country" : "Canada",
"totalTreatmentArms" : 3,
"treatmentArms" : [ 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Mechanism",
        "mechanism" : "mechanism1"
    }, 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Mechanism",
        "mechanism" : "mechanism2"
    }, 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Package",
        "mechanism" : ""
    }
]
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("579cabac6aba30f42a57a97b"),
"iecode" : "P2222",
"country" : "India",
"totalTreatmentArms" : 1,
"treatmentArms" : [ 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Package",
        "mechanism" : ""
    }
]
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("579cabe76aba30f42a57a97c"),
"iecode" : "P3333",
"country" : "India",
"totalTreatmentArms" : 2,
"treatmentArms" : [ 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Mechanism",
        "mechanism" : "mechanism1"
    }, 
    {
        "mechanismOrPkg" : "Package",
        "mechanism" : ""
    }
]
}
```

Please note that there are two records with `iecode : P1111` and I want result distinguished on `iecode` so only one record will be considered(any one).

Now my requirement is I want count on field `mechanismOrPkg`. If it contains value `Package` then we will increment `package` with one. If the value is `Mechanism` then we will consider value of field `mechanism` and its respected values count will be considered.

So final result will be like this

```
{
"_id" : null,
"totalPackage" : 3,
"totalMechanism1" : 2,
"totalMechanism2" : 1
}
```

Please ask if it sounds confusing. Let me know even if this kind of aggregation is possible with query or I have to do server side filtering?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Possible values of mechanismOrPkg : Package or Mechanism

Possible values of mechanism : mechanism1 or mechanism2

Comment: you should also specify if all documents `mechanism` value where  `mechanismOrPkg` is `Mechanism` can only have 2 values (`mechanism1`, `mechanism2`) as in yours example or amount of possible mechanisms is not restricted by yours application and it could be `mechanism3`, `mechanism4`, ... so the result document will be of different length depending on the particular collection state

Comment: @tarashypka Thanks for noting. Check my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accomplishing the above would require using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator in the [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator. The **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator will evaluate a logical condition based on its first argument (if) and then returns the second argument where the evaluation is true (then) or the third argument where false (else). This converts the `true/false` logic into 1 and 0 numerical values that feed into [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) respectively. So for instance, when you want to aggregate the count for the "Package" value, the logic follows:

```
{
    "$sum": { 
        "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package" ] }, 1, 0 ]
    }
}
```

---

As a resulting pipeline, you need to run the aggregation operation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$iecode",
            "treatmentArms": { "$first": "$treatmentArms" }
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$treatmentArms" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "totalPackage": { 
                "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [ 
                       { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Package" ] }, 
                       1, 0
                    ] 
                }
            },
            "totalMechanism1":{
                "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [ 
                        { 
                            "$and": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Mechanism" ] },
                                { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanism", "mechanism1" ] }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        1, 
                        0 ]
                }
            },
            "totalMechanism2": { 
                "$sum": { 
                   "$cond": [ 
                        { 
                            "$and": [
                                { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanismOrPkg", "Mechanism" ] },
                                { "$eq": [ "$treatmentArms.mechanism", "mechanism2" ] }
                            ]
                        }, 
                        1, 
                        0 ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "totalPackage" : 3,
    "totalMechanism1" : 2,
    "totalMechanism2" : 1
}
```

Comment: I am getting `0 records fetched`. I think first grouping should be done on `iecode`.

Comment: Are you running the aggregate operation on the right collection? As you can see, the first grouping IS actually grouping by the `iecode` field.

Comment: sorry about that(grouping). Yes I am querying right collection still same result.

Comment: If I remove ` { "$unwind": "$treatmentArms" }` then I am getting result but all values are zero.

Comment: I checked it on the collection you provided and have an expected result, aggregate query is correct. It should be something with your collection or you have mistakenly copied the query from an answer. Check the query again and make sure that your collection is exactly the same as in your question.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince Create another answer about your new issues, and I am sure that somebody will help you. Comments are not for long answers, but only for short clarification purposes. Also try to demonstrate there your attempts in solving the problem.